# Using SSIS to create new Database from two separate databases

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, ssis, etl

I am new to SSIS.I got the task have according to the scenario as explained.

Scenario:

I have two databases A and B on different machines and have around 25 tables and 20 columns with relationships and dependencies. My task is to create a database C with selected no of tables and in each table I don't require all the columns but selected some. Conditions to be met are that the relationships should be intact and created automatically in new database.

What I have done:

- I have created a package using the transfer SQL Server object task to transfer the tables and relationships.
- then I have manually edited the columns that are not required
- and then I transferred the data using the data source and destination

My question is: can I achieve all these things in one package? Also after I have transferred the data how can I schedule the package to just transfer the recently inserted rows in the database to the new database?

Please help me
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can schedule the package by using a SQL Server Agent Job - one of the options for a job step is run SSIS package.

With regard to transferring new rows, I would either:

- Track your current "position" in another table, assumes you have either an ascending key or a time stamp column - load the current position into an SSIS variable, use this variable in the WHERE statement of your data source queries.
- Transfer all data across into "dump" copies of each table (no relationships/keys etc required just the same schema) & use a T-SQL MERGE statement to load new rows in, then truncate "dump" tables.

Hope this makes sense - its a bit difficult to get across in writing.

Comment: hi, thanks for the reply my problem is that i am a newbie to ssis and still in process of learning a lot if you can please guide me through or suggest some tutorials that would of great help

Comment: Google "SSIS Junkie" should find you Jamie Thompson's blog - that's where I learned most of my SSIS.